# CTE Recursive Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table with records of employees that shows a relationship of employees and who they report to:

```
From_ID   position          TO_ID   position
----------------------------------------
1         Lowest_employee   3       employee
3         employee          4       employee
4         employee          5       BOSS
2         Lowest_employee   6       employee
6         employee          3       employee
10        Lowest_employee   50      BOSS2
```

I would like to show results that look like this, with the employee / boss IDs:

```
EmployeeID   BossID
--------------------
1            5
2            5
10           50
```

[image]

This means employees 1 and 2 report to ID 5 and employee 10 reports to another boss with ID 50.

I know I need to use CTE and Recursive Queries, but cannot understand how it can be done, I'm newer to CTE Recursive Queries.

I read this article but it doesn't  make any sense to me [MS link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Any help with the query required to achieve this would be useful.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what it is you are asking, re-read your question (forgetting what you know) and see if you think it makes any sense to someone that has no idea about your problem.

Comment: actually his question is pretty clear

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: is there any level "upper" than Boss ?

Comment: @hoangnnm really? I've read it a few times and I'm just getting an idea of what is going on. If you have to read it multiple times to understand, then it's not that clear.. in my opinion

Comment: so I  need to show each lower employee (1,2,10) who report  to BOSS (id 5 and 10 )

Comment: @hoangnnm I don't think that  there is some one upper than BOSS and BOSS2 (ID 5 and 10 )

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and make it more clear :)

Comment: The SQL Server documentation has nearly this exact use-case in the Recursive CTE section: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: sql fiddle from @Quassnoi's answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98a38/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This includes setting up test data, however I think this is what you want:

Test Data:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    From_ID int, 
    TO_ID int
)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(1,3)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(3,4)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(4,5)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(2,6)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(6,3)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(10,50)
```

Query to get answer:

```
;WITH Hierarchy (Employee, Superior, QueryLevel)
AS
(
    --root is all employees that have no subordinates
    SELECT  E.From_ID, E.TO_ID, 1
    FROM    @Table E
    LEFT
    JOIN    @Table S
            ON  S.TO_ID = E.From_ID
    WHERE   S.TO_ID IS NULL
    --recurse up tree to final superior
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  H.Employee, S.TO_ID, H.QueryLevel + 1
    FROM    Hierarchy H
    JOIN    @Table S
            ON  S.From_ID = H.Superior
)
SELECT Employee, Superior 
FROM
(
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY QueryLevel DESC) AS RowNumber 
    FROM Hierarchy
) H
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Essentially, this works by :

1) get all employees with no reportees (the root)

2) recurses up through the bosses, recording the 'level'

3) use over/partition to select only the 'final' boss

Comment: so that  means I have to create this table or its here just  for testing  purpose?

Comment: Just for test purposes - replace @Table with the table you already have :)

Comment: the only problem  with query  is :) `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: this most probably means you have loops in your data (unless you're working in a company with more than 100 tiers of management, of course)

Comment: @Quassnoi, yes it is, is there any way to make more loops maybe couple thousands:) ?

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: append `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the end of the query. Note that if you do have loops (which you most probably do), this query will never end by itself and would ultimately exhaust the server resources, severely impacting its performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH    q (employee, boss) AS
        (
        SELECT  fromId, toId
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   fromId NOT IN
                (
                SELECT  toId
                FROM    mytable
                )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  employee, toId
        FROM    q
        JOIN    mytable t
        ON      t.fromId = boss
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   boss NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  fromId
        FROM    mytable
        )
```

Comment: was preparing a similar answer as you posted, so you can add this fiddle with your code if you like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98a38/1

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this?

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE (
    EmployeeId INT,
    PositionName VARCHAR(50),
    ReportsToId INT);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (1, 'Driver', 3);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (3, 'Head of Driving Pool', 4);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (4, 'Corporate Flunky', 5);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (2, 'Window Cleaner', 6);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (6, 'Head of Office Services', 3);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (10, 'Minion', 50);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (5, 'BOSS', NULL);
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES (50, 'BOSS2', NULL);
WITH Employees AS (
    SELECT
        EmployeeId,
        1 AS [Level],
        EmployeeID AS [Path],
        ISNULL(ReportsToId, EmployeeId) AS ReportsToId
    FROM 
        @Employees
    WHERE 
        ReportsToId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        e.EmployeeID,
        x.[Level] + 1 AS [Level],
        x.[Path] + e.EmployeeID AS [Path],
        x.ReportsToId
    FROM 
        @Employees e
        INNER JOIN Employees x ON x.EmployeeID = e.ReportsToId)
SELECT
    ec.EmployeeId,
    e.PositionName,
    ec.[Level],
    CASE WHEN ec.ReportsToId = ec.EmployeeId THEN NULL ELSE ec.ReportsToId END AS ReportsToId --Can't really report to yourself
FROM 
    Employees ec
    INNER JOIN @Employees e ON e.EmployeeId = ec.EmployeeId
ORDER BY 
    ec.[Path];
```